# Format date time in Google Chart by timezone

Tags: google-visualization, formatter, timezone-offset

I am using Google Charts for line graphs and tables in my application. I have my data in UTC format however while displaying I want to change the timezone to the user's choice of timezone. 
For the tables, I tried using the timezone attribute for the date formatter. However it is not giving proper results. Hence I am planning to use moment.js to format the data in specific timezone. Can I use a custom formatter with data tables. The examples in the documentation do not have any details. Similarly can I format the data displayed on the x-axis of my line graph using a custom formatter. Any example would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the data in the DataTable by calling the `setFormattedValue` method of the `DataTable`: `data.setFormattedValue(row, column, 'string formatted value');`.  You cannot use the `format` property of the axis option to change the timezone, but you can use the `ticks` property of the axis option to set which dates and associated labels to use:

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: [{v: new Date(2014, 2, 1, 10), f: '03/01/2014 5AM EST'}, {v: new Date(2014, 2, 2, 17), f: '03/02/2014 12PM EST'}, {v: new Date(2014, 2, 3, 6), f: '03/03/2014 1AM EST'}]
}
```

It might be easier to adjust your data rather than to reformat things.  As an example, to change dates in column 1 of `data` from GMT by `offset` hours, you could use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var d = data.getValue(i, 0);
    d.setHours(d.getHours + offset);
    data.setValue(i, 0, d);
}
```